# How to make static array in Kotlin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, object-class

I am trying to make a static array in Kotlin. For doing this, I created an Object class, and inside that declared a `mutableListOf<PersonModel>()`.

When I try to add new `Object PersonModel` to array, I get red underline suggesting error in last line, which says `Expecting member declaration`.

**Code**

```kotlin
object Data {
    
    val array = mutableListOf<PersonModel> (PersonModel("roshan",65,50,"White",21,"male"))
    
    array.add(PersonModel("roshan",65,50,"White",21,"male"))
  
}
```

Comment: array.add statment needs to be inside a function.

Comment: What you have there is a list, not an array. [`Array`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/) and [`List`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/) have specific meanings in Kotlin, so it's best not to confuse them. (Lists are preferred, as they're more flexible and more general; arrays are mainly limited to varargs, low-level implementation, and interoperability.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use arbitrary executable code inside object/class declaration. This code block is only for defining of class members. If you want to execute some code when the class is instantiated, you can use initialization block:

```kotlin
object Data {
    
    val array = mutableListOf<PersonModel> (PersonModel("roshan",65,50,"White",21,"male"))
    
    init {
        array.add(PersonModel("roshan",65,50,"White",21,"male"))
    }
}
```

If you prefer to keep initialization code for a member in a single place, a common pattern is to use [scope function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html), for example `run()` or `apply()`:

```kotlin
val array = mutableListOf<PersonModel>().apply {
    add(PersonModel("roshan",65,50,"White",21,"male"))
    add(PersonModel("roshan",65,50,"White",21,"male"))
}
```

In your specific case, you don't have to do this, because you can create a list with both items directly:

```kotlin
val array = mutableListOf<PersonModel> (
    PersonModel("roshan",65,50,"White",21,"male"),
    PersonModel("roshan",65,50,"White",21,"male"),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion code:

//
place the object class constructor
//

```
class PersonModel (var name: String, var a: Int, var b: Int, var color: String, var c: Int, var sex: String)
```

//
create your first object
//

```
val array = mutableListOf<PersonModel>(PersonModel("roshan",65,50,"White",21,"male"))
```

//
add the second object
//

```
array.add(PersonModel("minotiana",30,10,"White",21,"Male"))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As it stands, this is not sufficient as an answer, since it would not be helpful if the link didn't work. Can you edit the answer to include the main point?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As written by [@Arpit Shukl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13308991/arpit-shukla) in the comments, one cannot add arbitrary statements such as `array.add(...)` to the body of an object (or class) declaration.

To achieve a statically initialized, globally available variable (or value) in Kotlin, you have multiple options.

**Top-level declaration**

In Kotlin you can declare `var`iables / `val`ues and `fun`ctions on the top-level without the need for a wrapping object (or class).

```kotlin
package com.example.models

val availablePersonModels = listOf(
    PersonModel("roshan", 65, 50, "White", 21, "male")
)
```

```kotlin
import com.example.models.availablePersonModels

fun foo() {
    for (availablePersonModel in availablePersonModels) {
        println(availablePersonModel)
    }
}
```

If you want to be able to add / remove items from the list after initialization, simply exchange `listOf` with `mutableListOf`.

**Object declaration**

If you want to group several declarations together or make the declaration context more explicit, you may wrap the declaration in an `object`.

```kotlin
object ModelProvider {
    val availablePersonModels = listOf(
        PersonModel("roshan", 65, 50, "White", 21, "male")
    )
}
```

```kotlin
import com.example.models.ModelProvider

fun foo() {
    for (availablePersonModel in ModelProvider.availablePersonModels) {
        println(availablePersonModel)
    }
}
```

---

**Initializing static values using statements**

The `listOf` and `mutableListOf` function calls support being passed values to add to the created `List`, thus you do NOT need to call `add(...)` as part of the initialization. However, that must not be the case always.
E.g. there might be classes that need to be instantiated with an empty constructor and filled with values by calling setters afterdwards.

```kotlin
class ExampleClass {
    var x: Int? = null
    var y: Int? = null
}
```

Using the object declaration above, you might want to add such calls into the `constructor` of the `object`, e.g.:

```kotlin
object ModelProvider {
    val exampleValue = ExampleClass()

    init {
        exampleValue.x = 1
        exampleValue.y = 1
    }
}
```

Instead of splitting the initialization and population like above, you might also use a single expression for both, e.g. using one of the [scope functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html) such as `apply`, e.g.:

```kotlin
val exampleValue = ExampleClass().apply {
    x = 1
    y = 1
}
```

Of course this can be used inside an `object` as well, removing the need for the `init` block.